# Can computer be safe without antivirus?

Tags: anti-virus

I don't like anti-virus much because it slows down my pc so I wonder if Is there any tip to prevent virus's infection without installing anti-virus ?

Comment: Yes, don't do "stupid" things

Comment: I follow these [3 Basic Rules for Online Safety](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2011/05/krebss-3-basic-rules-for-online-safety/)

Comment: Your question does not make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Don't connect to a network, and don't use any CDs, DVDs, diskettes, memory sticks, etc.  And don't use a telephone modem either.

Comment: I recall about 20 years back a situation with a Gigantic Computer Company where PCs plugged into the *internal* network would be infected before one had time to download the "blessed" antivirus product.  (We practically had to stage a riot to get the network admins to seek out and shut down the rogue systems that were distributing the virus.)  Systems out of the box are a little more secure now, but there is always a risk.

Comment: short answer, no. even perfectly reputable sites include content from ad networks that are not reputable, and there is always a 0-day exploit for flash/acrobat/java out there and a server that's happy to p0wn you with it.

Answer (score 2):

This may sound extreme, but the only way I know to make a computer **perfectly safe** from viruses is:

**Unplug it**

[image: Unplug it]

Even PCs without an internet connection can be infected by media inserted for use (CDs, DVDs, flash drives, etc.).

Being online without virus protection is like running around a cage of lions with meat strapped to you.

[image: lion]

You will eventually get caught and it won't be pleasant.

There are several basic antivirus programs which run without using a lot of resources which would be worth using. *"It's better to have it and not need it, than to need it and not have it"*.